# Finding position of cursor with window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to find the cursor is at the top of a HTML element with window scroll function.

EDIT: I have to call the below script to suspend the window scroll function if the cursor is at the top of one div:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
   console.log(e);
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   e.cancelBubble = false;
   return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: You don't need the window scroll function in that story. Just a hover function

Comment: what do you want actually? position of cursor? or hover effect on an element when cursor on it??

Comment: I need to suspend the window scroll function if the cursor is on the top of an element.. Is this possible?

Comment: let me explain a bit more... I have to call the below script to suspend the window scroll function if the cursor is at the top of one div ==============================


document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
   console.log(e);
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   e.cancelBubble = false;
   return false;
   }, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that you want to prevent scrolling from occuring if the mouse cursor is (hovered) over a particular element then take the function you supplied and add a conditional so that the DOMMouseScroll event is cancelled only when a flag isn't set:

```
var allowScroll = true;

$("div.noscroll").hover(function() {
    allowScroll = false;
}, function() {
    allowScroll = true;
});

document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    if (!allowScroll) {
        console.log(e);
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.cancelBubble = false;
        return false;
    }
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WSQbp/

Given that you've tagged your question with "jquery" I've used jQuery to setup the hover handler that manages the flag. You could further simplify your code by using jQuery to setup your DOMMouseScroll handler:

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    if (!allowScroll)
        return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WSQbp/1/